# Sklearn random forest regressor predictions are all the same

Tags: python, machine-learning, scikit-learn, random-forest, prediction

I'm using Scikit Learn version 1.1.1 to build a random forest regressor for a dataset but whenever I run it, it returns predictions that are all the same. This is the code that I'm using.

```
# Set target and feature variables
target = merged_df[target_variable]
merged_df.drop(target_variable, axis=1, inplace=True)

features_list = list(merged_df.columns)

# Adjust features being used based on user input
if (features == all):
    features_list = features_list
elif (type(features) == list):
    using_features = []
    for element in features:
        using_features.append(features_list.index(element))
    features_list = using_features
    
X = merged_df
y = target

# Set training and testing groups
train_features, test_features, train_target, test_target = train_test_split(X, y, random_state=rdm_state)
print(train_features)
print(test_features)
print(train_target)
print(test_target)
# Train model

rf = RandomForestRegressor()
rf.fit(train_features, train_target)

# Make predictions and calculate error
predictions = rf.predict(test_features)
```

and predictions is an array of all the same number.

Why is this happening?

Comment: Probably this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/q/76197241/10452700) could help